# Equation solver in Python

Tags: python, parsing, equation-solving

Given a simple equation such as:

```
x = y + z
```

You can get the third variable if you bind the other two (ie: `y = x - z` and `z = x - y`). A straightforward way to put this in code:

```
def solve(args):
    if 'x' not in args:
        return args['y'] + args['z']
    elif 'z' not in args:
        return args['x'] - args['y']
    elif 'y' not in args:
        return args['x'] - args['z']
    else:
        raise SomeError
```

I obviously can take an equation, parse it and simplify it to achieve the same effect. 
But I believe in doing so I would be re-inventing the wheel. So where's my ready-made wheel?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider using [Sympy](http://code.google.com/p/sympy/). It includes various tools to solve equations and a lot more.

The following is an excerpt from the [docs](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/solvers/solvers.html):

```
>>> from sympy import I, solve
>>> from sympy.abc import x, y

>>> solve(x**4-1, x)
[1, -1, -I, I]
```